# Executing bash script in an EC2 instance from a Lambda Function

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, dbt

For a project I am working on we are trying to execute a bash script in an EC2 instance from a Lambda function. The bash script in turn executes `dbt run`. The problem we are facing is we can execute the bash script executes commands like `mkdir` successfully, but it is not executing `dbt run`.

The following is our code to trigger bash script in the EC2 instance

```
import time
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

    response = ssm.send_command(
        InstanceIds=['instance_id'],
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={'commands': ['bash /path/to/bash_script.sh']}
    )
```

Content of `bash_script.sh`

```
dbt run --project-dir /path/to/dbtvault/
```

Comment: Can it help ? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/

Comment: Is there a log where you can view the output of an SSM command? Or perhaps you can simply use `dbt run --project-dir /path/to/dbtvault/ >>/tmp/ssm_dbt_log.txt` and see what it says?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I checked the syslog there isn't anything. I will try to add log like you've suggested and see what happens.

Comment: I would try to put the full path of the `dbt` executable in your call.  As in, `/usr/local/bin/dbt run --project-dir /path/to/dbtvault`.

Comment: I would try connecting via SSH first, running the command, and getting the output in real-time, maybe you could understand more from it.